# How easy/fast are support vector machines to create/update?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

If I provided you with data sufficient to classify a bunch of objects as either apples, oranges or bananas, how long might it take you to build an SVM that could make that classification? I appreciate that it probably depends on the nature of the data, but are we more likely talking hours, days or weeks?

Ok. Now that you have that SVM, and you have an understanding of how the data behaves, how long would it likely take you to upgrade that SVM (or build a new one) to classify an extra class (tomatoes) as well? Seconds? Minutes? Hours?

The motivation for the question is trying to assess the practical suitability of SVMs to a situation in which not all data is available to be sampled at any time. Fruit are an obvious case - they change colour and availability with the season.

If you would expect SVMs to be too fiddly to be able to create inside 5 minutes on demand, despite experience with the problem domain, then suggestions of a more user-friendly form of classifier for such a situation would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by building an SVM? Do you want to code SVM from scratch for a very simple data?

Comment: No - the data will not be simple. It will involve image-based measurements of colour, size, shape, etc of each object, so probably at least 5-10 dimensions. Because the data set is continually expanding (like face recognition, perhaps) and likely to end up with 1000s of samples, the retraining time is the critical performance aspect that concerns me.

Comment: Ok. So you are not trying to build the SVM from scratch. Also, if you are looking at 1000-dimensional space (don't care upto 200-300 dimensional space) in combination with 10000s of sample then SVM might start proving very expensive. Then you can turn to something called as `Random Forest`.

Comment: @Parag - Random Forest looks interesting... but the graphic illustration of overfitting on Wikipedia makes it look unworkable!

Comment: Don't worry about overfitting. Trust me, Random Forest works quite as well as SVM on most of the scenarios. It is designed to handle large data and multi-class problem. Its a well-established algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, adding a class to a 1 vs. many SVM classifier requires retraining all classes. In case of large data sets, this might turn out to be quite expensive. In the real world, when facing very large data sets, if performance and flexibility are more important than state-of-the-art accuracy, Naive Bayes is quite widely used (adding a class to a NB classifier requires training of the new class only).

However, according to your comment, which states the data has tens of dimensions and up to 1000s of samples, the problem is relatively small, so practically, SVM retrain can be performed very fast (probably, in the order of seconds to tens of seconds).

Comment: "Generally, adding a class to a 1 vs. many SVM classifier requires retraining all classes" Yes, on the classical C-SVM this might be true. However, depending of the problem sometimes you could use regression instead and map each class to a range of values, that way is only one problem to be solve and not C problems (where C is the number of classes)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give us more details about your problem, since there are too many different scenarios where SVM can be trained fairly quickly (I could train it in real time in a third person shooting game and not have any latency) or it could last several minutes (I have a case for a face detector that training took an hour long)

As a thumb rule, the training time is proportional to the number of samples and the dimension of each vector.

Comment: Perhaps you could share the number of samples and dimensionality of the data for each of the shooting game and face detector examples. I can imagine very fast face detectors, and very slow shooting games. I can also imagine a game will envisage all scenarios in advance, while face detectors might need to have new faces added all the time. If you can edit your answer to provide more detail, that would be very helpful :-)

Comment: @omatai Well my point was that if the problem is small enough one could afford to even retrain it in the middle of a game. That specific example was a proof of concept that I did for my master's dissertation. It was a tiny problem (5 features and something like 500 samples) but game logic is a well bounded problem so that was more than enough to show my point. If you are curious about the performance you can check this video(http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mh_DvxRvGYo) it's not self explanatory but shows what I did. The face detector had an input vector of 30x30 and something like 15000 samples